# DTD must be defined before the document root element

Tags: c#, xml

Необходимо прочитать sitemap.xml и закинуть все ссылки в список, для последующего обхода. Использую следующий код, получаю ошибку, описанную выше. Как исправить эту ситуацию? sitemap.xml править нельзя(!).

```
    public List<string> CreateList()
    {
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();
        
        XmlDocument obj = new XmlDocument();

        obj.Load(url);

        XmlNodeList elemList = obj.GetElementsByTagName("loc");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            temp.Add(elemList[i].InnerXml);
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Покажите этот sitemap.xml, если он не слишком большой.

Comment: К сожалению, нет возможности - подписывал документы=) Я уже погуглил и разобрался, нашёл другой способ парсить sitemap

Comment: @kEdo, Как уже сказал Александр ... Пожалуйста, отредактируйте исходный пост и добавьте файл **sitemap.xml**. Без него невозможно помочь.

Comment: Небось, регулярками? / Вообще, согласно спецификации xml, DTD должен быть расположен в начале файла. Если это не так, значит это не xml, а просто текстовый файл. Точка. / Однако, быстрый поиск находит много похожих вопросов. Парсеры могут выдавать такую ошибку ложно. Думаю, дело в некорректном составлении xml. Кто-то писал в файл ручками, не используя API для работы с xml. В итоге получился не well-formed xml (неправильно сформатированный) с неэкранированными символами. Мораль: всегда создавайте xml правильно, с помощью классов для работы с ним.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в xml document. При попытке считать фай сбрасывается ошибка.

Comment: Я даже знаю, в каком месте ошибка=) Вопрос в том, как обойти необходимость считывать DTD